# Can't run an Android application on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD in Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, adb

After installing Eclipse Luna and set up the environment to develop Android applications I have tried to run an application on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD. Then, neither eclipse nor the `adb devices` command detect the device even though I have enabled usb debugging in the device. Moreover the `lsusb` command does not list the USB connection for the device.
So I followed the android tutorial http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html but in the list of USB Vendor ID BQ as a vendor does not appear. I've searched a little bit and I have found that BQ USB Vendor ID was 2207 although I'm not sure. At this point it still does not work. I am stuck at this point and I do not know what to try or how to continue.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem recently, but in my case was an aquaris 4.5. At least, in ubuntu, I added the next string to the file located in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a47", MODE="0666" , ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c02|2008", TAG+="uaccess"
```

Be careful with the idProduct. In my case, lsusb returns the following code:

```
   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 2a47:0c02
```

Just replace idProduct value with the one of your device. Then execute:

```
    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

And after that kill the adb server, launch it again, disconnect your device from the pc and reconnect it again. Cross your fingers and maybe, it will be listed with the adb devices :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I realized that the `lsusb` command was not detecting my device because the USB cable was not making proper connection although the charging LED was on. Before editing the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file` I edited the `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` file and I added the vendor ID, so it looks like this:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE. 
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE. 
0x2a47
```

After doing that and try the adb devices command, I get an alert in my Bq asking me to authorize my laptop. Next, the device appeared in the adb device list.

It was useful for me to resort to the Bq Official website forum, specially this link:
http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/discussion/35998/conseguir-que-eclipse-o-android-studio-reconozcan-nuestro-bq-en-ubuntu/p1